# Django 2 get user `id` upon making request on forms.py failing with null

Tags: python, django

Exactly as the title says. The `session` itself is active and not outdated either.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: can we have a look at your `T` model?

Comment: Adding it now. Thanks @Lemayzeur

Comment: @Lemayzeur - added it. Let me know what you think. I'm at a real loss - thanks

Comment: At first glance, it's just because the ForeignKey `FKtoUser` can't be `null` when saving a new record for `T`. so that's why you got this `Column 'FKtoUser_id' cannot be null` .. You need to add a user instance

Comment: @Lemayzeur - I'm trying to get the `id` from the currently signed in user. from `auth.user`. As stated there are already (2) users in this table. And one is signed in

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: `d.FKtoClient_id = current_user.id` with this, you're not assinging value to the foreignkey, the field name is `FKtoUser`.. so it would be `d.FKtoUser = current_user` dont't use the ID by the way, just the instance

Comment: @Lemayzeur - this at least changes the error to: `Cannot assign "2": "Tld.FKtoUser" must be a "User" instance.` How can I resolve this?